# Creating Unit test in VB for a method which uses web.config inside

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

The Vb method is like

```
Public Sub GetDataTable (ByVal input As String ) As DataTable

    //do some logic  based on 
    //checks ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UserName")

Return A Datatable
```

while Creating unit test for this how to pass the username value which is not in the input parameters

Already added same app.config in the test project , didnt work

Comment: You can use the same appSettings in your unit test project's app.config.

Comment: already tried that . not working

Comment: I use a different syntax, but it definitely works. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UserName")`

Comment: @shaswatatripathy Ok not working does not tell us much. Adding the setting to the config file used by the unit test is suppose to work so then there is something additional in your setup that we are not aware of

Comment: it worked , without Get as @Crowcoder said . thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CrowCoder

Add the usernames in app.config of the test project